# SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON

Tags: node.js, angular, http

So I'm getting this error that apparently every other noob angular dev gets. Trying to do some testing on a landing page where I register emails to my database, but I get this Syntax error every time.

error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/lorenzowhite/Desktop/Work Stuff/projectus/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

landing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidateService } from '../../services/validate.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.css']
})
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {
  email: String;

  constructor(
    private validateService: ValidateService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.email)
    if(!this.validateService.validateEmail(this.email)){
      console.log("please use valid email")
      return false
    } else {
      this.authService.registerEmail(this.email).subscribe(data =>{
        if(data.success){
          console.log('you are now registered')
        } else {
          console.log('you are not registered')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  userEmail: any;

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  registerEmail(userEmail){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let opts = {headers: headers}
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/notifyme', userEmail, opts)
      .map(res => res.json())
  }

}
```

users/notifyme route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/users')

router.post('/notifyme', (req, res, next) =>{
  let newUser = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
  })

  User.addEmail(newUser, (err, user)=>{
    if(err){
      res.json({success:false, msg: "failed to register"})
    } else {
      res.json({sucess:true, msg: "registered email"})
    }
  })})


module.exports = router;
```

and then the `addEmail` function literally just saves an email to the db.

Comment: how does the `userEmail ` object look ?

Comment: It's not an object, it's just the name I gave for the res.body.email value that I'd be passing along to the addEmail function to save it to the db